# UndefinedBehaviorSanitiser Issue - CS50 Vigenere

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I am working on Vigenere (CS50) and keep getting an "UndefinedBehaviorSanitiser SEGV on Unknown Address" when I run my program with any argument that passes the initial screening.

I have read about this issue but cannot find the solution. I cut my code down as much as I could and found the problem occurs even when I do this part. Where is the issue?
Thank you so much.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//int shift(char c);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
        {
        printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword");
        return 1;
        }
    else
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
            {
            if (!isalpha(argv[1]))
            {
                printf("Usage: ./vigenere keyword");
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("All good!");
                return 1;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is a `string`. The argument to `isalpha()` must be a `char`. How did this even compile without warnings about that type mismatch?

Comment: `isalpha(argv[1])` should be `isalpha(argv[1][i])`.

Comment: most precisely it should be `isalpha((unsigned char)argv[1][i])`, and everything else is wrong and can cause undefined behaviour, including your crash.

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately GCC does not give any diagnostics.

Comment: @Remitto I upvoted your question because you've managed to produce an almost perfectly minimal example that demonstrates the issue *and* all the compiler diagnostics (which are none), and the explanation of what happened. To get even better you could verify that the crash indeed occurs on the `isalpha` line (you could replace the entire call with `1` and then `0` and verify that it works as it should).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Wow, you're right. LLVM warns, but GCC doesn't, even with `-Wall` and `-pedantic`.

Comment: @remitto, you're not supposed to *fix* your question. I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix indeed is

```
if (!isalpha((unsigned char)argv[1][i]))
```

The `isalpha` function/macro takes only a single integer, which must have the value of a single character as *`unsigned char`*. But `argv[1]` is a pointer to multiple characters!

Now as an extra complication, the `isalpha` is often realized as a macro, and often coded so that a compiler  does not produce *any* diagnostics for a wrong type of argument. This is unfortunate, but you just *need* to know these when you're programming in C.

The cast of `char` to `unsigned char` is required too - if not, then any extended characters (i.e. for example `ä`) will invoke undefined behaviour on platforms where `char` is signed - and they **are** on x86 processors - because the value will be negative, but `isalpha` would expect just a number that is either `EOF` or a non-negative number less than or equal to `UCHAR_MAX`.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I almost didn't post this as I expected I'd missed something basic and I'd feel like an idiot and I wasn't wrong. Thanks for pointing that out though, I'll try again.